# Xamarin IOS change view controller of tab item

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to use Xamarin iOS TabBar Controller.

My Scenario.

There are three tabs, Tab 1, Tab 2 & Tab 3. 
There are four screens, Screen 1, Screen 2, Screen 3, Screen 4.

So Tab 1 shows Screen 1, Tab 2 shows Screen 2 and Tab 3 shows Screen 3. There is a button on Screen 3, on click of that button, Tab 3 needs to show Screen 4.

I am struggling with this. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just presenting a view controller as you would normally do?

Comment: Yes, I have but then new VewController hides the tab as Screen 4 is not a tab of TabBarController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [UINavigationController](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UINavigationController/).  That Nav will be the root view of tab3, and will contain Screen3.  When the button on Screen3 is tapped, it will use

```
Navigation.PushViewController(new Screen4(), true);
```

to navigate to Screen4.

Comment: I can not use UINavigationController, because my initial Screen (one time screen) has no tabs and navigation and from 2nd screen onward i have tabs on screens, thus using TabBarController. I will like to use Navigation controller but not getting a way to set it rootviewcontroller from second screen onward.

Comment: you can have navigation within each tab of a tabbar.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of example, Lets call `Screen3` -> `ThirdViewController` - which is displayed when you click Tab 3. Lets call `Screen4` -> `FourthViewController`.

In order to navigate from `ThirdViewController` -to-> `FourthViewController` you need to first wrap the `ThirdViewController` in a `UINavigationController` and then simply call [PushViewController](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UINavigationController.PushViewController/) to navigate to the `FourthViewController`.

Example using StoryBoard:
https://github.com/pnavk/XamarinTabsDemo

[image]

Comment: I am not using UINavigationController. I am using Tab Bar Controller. TabBarController does not have PushViewController method

Comment: Okay, but in order to do navigation, you have to wrap your `Screen3` in a  UINavigationController. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/

Comment: I can not use UINavigationController, because my initial Screen (one time screen) has no tabs and navigation and from 2nd screen onward i have tabs on screens, thus using TabBarController. I will like to use Navigation controller but not getting a way to set it rootviewcontroller from second screen onward.

Comment: Could you post some code on how you are setting up your TabBarController? That way I can provide an example

Comment: I just added image of my story board. I hope it helps

Comment: @Sumit I uploaded an example of what you are trying to accomplish using StoryBoard.